# Can't run Jquery methods inside Template.onRendered?

Tags: meteor

Sorry if this question may sound stupid but I'm getting an error that I can't make sense of. I have the following code in onRendered:

```
Template.displayItem.onRendered(function(){
  if ($('div.item')[0]) {
    console.log('First item found!');
    $('div.item')[0].hide();
  }
});
```

Now I can see the correct output `"First item found!"` in the console - this means Jquery selector is working and it found the element in the DOM, but the `.hide()` Jquery method was not executed and I'm getting the error message below:

```
Exception from Tracker afterFlush function:
TypeError: $(...)[0].hide is not a function
```

I'm not sure what causes this behavior. Has anyone encountered similar error(s)?

Comment: Usually you need to call Jquery functions on actual jquery objects. Try calling `$('div.item').hide()` instead. When you access index `[0]`, you're getting the actual DOM node and bypassing the Jquery object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$('div.item').first().hide()` instead. The array returned by your selector will contain DOM objects which don't have jQuery methods (like `hide`) attached to them. In contrast, [first](https://api.jquery.com/first/) will return a proper `jQuery` object.

Answer (score 0):

use $(this).hide()

```
  if ($('div.item')[0]) {
    console.log('First item found!');
     $(this).hide()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because `$('div.hide')[0]` is a plain node, and not a jquery object.

You should probably use `this.$('div.hide').first().hide()`